# How to display the cart value individual?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, shopping-cart

I am using the CodeIgniter shopping cart. I am fetching the product data using ajax.
Now in my ajax success
**Fetching data**

```
    public function viewPrimaryCart()
     {

      $output = '';
      $count = 0;
      foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items)
      {
       $count++;
       $output .= '
   <tr> 
    <td>'.$items["name"].'</td>
    <td>'.$items["qty"].'</td>
    <td>'.$items["price"].'</td>
    <td>'.$items["subtotal"].'</td>
    </tr>
   ';
      }
      if($count == 0)
      {
       $output = '<p>Nothing selected yet</p>';
      }
      return $output;

    }
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Member_controller/primaryMemberCart",
    method:"POST",
    data:{product_id:product_id, product_name:product_name, product_price:product_price,quantity:quantity},
    success:function(data)
    {
      alert(data);
     //alert("Product Added into Cart");
     $('#primarycart_details').html(data);
    }
   });
```

I  want to know how to display the cart data individual? I mean I have to get the quantity and pass to my jquery.

I tried

```
alert(data.qty),alert(data['qty']),alert(data[0]).
```

what is the correct way to display?
I refer this link for cart https://www.webslesson.info/2017/03/ajax-jquery-codeigniter-shopping-cart.html

Would you help me out on this issue?

Comment: hey, please update your ajax result.

Comment: what does `alert(data.qty)` return ?

Comment: @TarangP, I am getting  undefined

Comment: show your full ajax call

Comment: @TarangP, Why you deleted you answer? any other idea to solve this? I refer this website https://www.webslesson.info/2017/03/ajax-jquery-codeigniter-shopping-cart.html

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found my answer. I tried below code and it's working for me.

**Controller**

```
public function viewPrimaryCart()
 {
  $output = '';
  $count = 0;
  foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items)
  {
   $count++;
   $output = array('qty' =>$items["qty"],'subtotal'=>$items["subtotal"] );
  }
  if($count == 0)
  {
   $output = '<p>Nothing selected yet</p>';
  }

 echo json_encode($output);
 exit();
}
```

**Ajax success**

```
 success:function(data)
    {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
       alert(obj.qty);
       alert(obj.subtotal);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

it gonna be little complex

Your dataType: "json" tells jQuery that you want it to parse the returned JSON, it does not mean that jQuery will automatically stringify your request data.

use

```
dataType: "json"
```

And udpate your `view()` function like store whole view in one array like

```
$array  = ('view'=>'your_html_view_code','name'=>$items['name'],'name'=>$qty['qty'])
```

and send to response by encoding via `json_encode()`
And get values by `response.name`

Comment: Give me some time to check

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, There is some internet issue at my home. I tried your code and added alert(data.name) but I am not getting any alert. I tried alert(data) that also not displaying then I remove the dataTye:"json" and I am getting the alert

Comment: make sure you return json_encoded array from php file to response for ex. `json_encode(array('name'=>"some_name",'value'=>132));`

Comment: Wait I am updating the code again..I am using the CodeIgniter shopping cart.

Comment: I update my code please check it. I refer the website for add to cart https://www.webslesson.info/2017/03/ajax-jquery-codeigniter-shopping-cart.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class on the td quantity

```
$output .= '
       <tr> 
        <td>'.$items["name"].'</td>
        <td class="quantity">'.$items["qty"].'</td>
        <td>'.$items["price"].'</td>
        <td>'.$items["subtotal"].'</td>
       </tr>
       ';
```

Then u can get the value with jquery

```
$('.quantity').innerHTML();
```

Comment: I tried your code. I was getting the error that value is not a function then I try val but I am getting empty alert

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data); // add this part 
    alert(obj.qty);
}
```

Comment: without ajax response call, how can you get the data?

Comment: I think he is stuck in get success response data. perhaps,  in controller return data will json format

Comment: I tried your code but I am getting the error in the console JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 5 of the JSON data.... my ajax success is not a json